# How to set a different Dockerfile CMD depending on environment?

Tags: dockerfile

I need to set a different Dockerfile CMD depending on the environment I am in. In my particular case I need to run a different NPM script depending on whether I am in a dev, staging or production environment. I was wondering what the best way to do this would be?

For example in dev my CMD would be: CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ] and in production it would be: CMD [ "npm", "run", "prod" ].

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your env-dependent commands in a script.

`cmd.sh`

```
if [ "$ENV" -eq "production" ]; then
  npm prod
fi

if [ "$ENV" -eq "development" ]; then
  npm dev
fi
```

And, in `Dockerfile`;

```
...
COPY cmd.sh /workdir/cmd.sh
...
CMD [ "./cmd.sh" ]
```